# Hide login credentials in python 3

Tags: python-requests, hide, credentials, password-protection, password-encryption

I am writing a python script that sends a get request to a router. The problem is that the user and password are exposed to all in the script. I have seen multiple methods for dealing with this problem(using environment variables, reading credentials from a file) but these methods have not satisfied my needs. I would like that only a local admin user could have access to the file or variables that hold the user/pass values.

Comment: Put the credentials in a file that has permissions set to only be readable by the admin user, then open that file in the script?

Comment: the file needs to be shared so not an option... thanks though

Comment: What do you mean by 'shared'? There are secure mechanisms for distribution available for pushing files around.

Comment: You can use the `cryptography.fernet` module to encrypt the credentials and make is to that only the admin user has the key to decrypt. If the script is executed under his user, there is no reason why all the other users should need access to the decryption key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved this problem by encrypting my credentials with a permanent `fernet` key using the `cryptography` library. The permanent key is in a file in the same directory as the main code as well as the encrypted credentials. 
Thanks for the suggestions.